# How do I use for command to give me an output by file?

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I have a folder named `Chapters` which contains 20 files with 1 chapter of a book per file.

I have a file named `book_chap.list` which contains the list of chapters. It contains something like this:

```
chap_00
chap_01
```

I have a third file called `book.names10` which contains a list of names. It contains something like this:

```
Name1
Name2
```

What I need from the output is a file that indicates by chapter the times each name has been said in each chapter. Something like this:

```
chapters/chap_01:Name1
chapters/chap_01:Name1
chapters/chap_01:Name2
```

I am using this:

```
for a in chapters/chap_* ;
  do
    echo -n $a;
    ggrep -F -f book.names10 -w -o $a | wc -l ;
done
```

but the only thing I got is a list of the number of times the names were used in each chapter in general. I don't know where to integrate the file `book_chap.list` on this command.

Comment: does "Name 1" contain spaces? should "name" and "Name" count as same?

Comment: What is `book.ents10` that you use in your code? It would be nice to know the precise location of the files you mention in the question, that is not clear. Also, the expected output does not seem to match your description.

Comment: No it doesn't countain spaces and it should only count "Name". I edited the main post, "book.ents10" should be "book.names10", my makefile had the first one and I forgot to change it to the 2nd one. It is now fixed, I'm sorry for them confusion! Book.names10 is a file in wich there are the names that are mentioned throughout the chapters. book_chap.list and book.names10 are inside a directory and inside that directory there is another one called chapters which contains the files with the chapters divided.

Comment: `grep -Fwo -f book.names10 chapters/chap_*` Does this work? Without a `for` loop - just `grep` with multiple input files (matched by the glob pattern `chapters/chap_*`). If searching in all chapter files, `book_chap.list` seems unnecessary (glob pattern expands to a list of those files).

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty (you might want to prettify the output):

```
#!/bin/bash
for chapter in $(ls chapters/chap_*); do
    echo "Chapter ${chapter}:" >> nameOccurences.txt
    for name in $(cat book.names10); do
            echo -n "${name}: " >> nameOccurences.txt
            grep -o ${name} ${chapter} | wc -l >> nameOccurences.txt
    done
echo "" >> nameOccurences.txt
done
```

If you want to group the result by name rather than chapter, you have to exchange the loops and output accordingly.